# How to handle the 'Left mouse Clicked' Event of an Edit Box in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Dialog with 8 `Dynamic Read-Only Edit Boxes`, 7/8 of them will hold different text strings, and the last one is empty. What i'm trying to do is: when a user `clicks` at 1 of those `Edit Boxes` (which hold the text string), the text will be shown in the empty `Edit Box`. If you guys have any ideas on how this should be done, I would be grateful.

Here are some codes that i've tried:

```
void CTab1::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
        ...
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_TAB1CMTBOX, m_StrShow);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTab1, CDialog)
...
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(EN_SETFOCUS, 4000, 4100, &CTab1::OnEditBoxClicked)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CTab1::OnEditBoxClicked(UINT nID)
{
    switch (nID)
    {
    case 4001:

        GetDlgItemText(4001, m_CmtText);
        m_CmtText = m_StrShow; 
        UpdateData(FALSE);
        break;

    case 4003:
        GetDlgItemText(4003, m_CmtText);
        m_CmtText = m_StrShow;
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_TAB1CMTBOX, m_StrShow);//This line doesn't work
        UpdateData(FALSE);
        break;
...
}
```

Comment: Did but breakpoints at the appropriate lines and did you step through your code with the debugger? Did the breakpoiints get hit as you expected? And also those case labels with magic numbers is a bad idea (not related to your problem).

Comment: @Jabberwocky so my idea using ```ON_CONTROL_RANGE(EN_SETFOCUS,...)``` is on point, right ? And basically i'm bad at programming, i don't know how to set unique IDs for dynamic controls when using ```Create()```method, so i have to use those magic numbers. I know it was a bad idea, i'll try to find solution for this later.

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers, you should at least use `#define`s.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you for your solution. I'll try it. and tomorrow, when i'm done with this part i'll ask about this Unique IDs topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see You obviously only have swapped the variables.

```
void CTab1::OnEditBoxClicked(UINT nID)
{
   switch (nID)
   {
    case 4003:
      GetDlgItemText(4003, m_CmtText);  // Read ctrl Text to m_CmtString 
  //  m_CmtText = m_StrShow;            // then Write immediately m_strShow to m_CmtText.  Which make no sense
      m_StrShow = m_CmtText;            // <-- swapped
  //  SetDlgItemText(IDC_TAB1CMTBOX, m_StrShow);  // sure? You want show the Text in IDC_TAB1CMTBOX ?
      SetDlgItemText(IDC_SHOWBOX, m_StrShow); // replace IDC
      UpdateData(FALSE);
      break;
  ..
}
```

This is what I would do, simplify the code.

```
void CTab1::OnEditBoxClicked(UINT nID)
{
  if (UpdateData(TRUE))
  {
    GetDlgItemText(nID, m_CmtText);         // Read ctrl Text nID 
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_SHOWBOX, m_CmtText); // Show the ctrl nID Text to ShowBox
    UpdateData(FALSE);
  }
```

}